# How to make a variable global from inside a function node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i am trying to make this snmp variable global so i can save it in my mongoose database but i can not get it working, i have tried to declaring it as global and the window.data way but does not want to console.log outside my function. i am sure it is just a small thing but would greatly appreciate one of you guys taking a minute out of your day.

thanks in advance

```
session.get({ oid: [2, 8, 0] }, function(err, varbinds) {
  var vb;
  if (err) {  
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    vb = varbinds[0];  
  }
  console.log('The system description is "' + vb.value + '"');
  session.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node.js global variable like so:

```
GLOBAL.window = {};  // creates a global variable "window"
```

[Global Objects Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects)

Comment: thanks for the info but that will not work unfortunately,  would it be possible to call the function within the function and store that info in to the database.

Comment: var Voltage = mongoose.model('Voltage', {temp: Number});




    var Voltage = new Voltage({temp: 27});

    Voltage.save(function (err) {
        if (err)//....
            console.log('Done');
    });